# Proving that the Taylor exansions of $f$ is equal to $f$ at the order $n$.

Tags: derivatives, taylor-expansion

We say that two functions $f,g: \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ are equal at order $n$ at the point $a$ when
$$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(a+h)-g(a+h)}{h^n} = 0.$$

> (a) Show that $f$ is differetiable at $a$ iff there is a function $g$ of the form $g(x) = a_0 + a_1(x-a)$ such that $f,g$ are equal at the first order at $a$.
>
> (b) When there is $f'(a),...,f^{(n)}(a)$ its verified that the function $g$, defined by
> $$g(x) = \sum_0^{n}\frac{f^{(i)}(a)}{i!}(x-a)^i,$$
> is equal to $f$ at the order $n$ at the point $a$.

For the item (b), I don't know if I'm right, but I showed that
$$\lim_{x \to a}\frac{f^{(n)}(x) - f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}$$
by using the l'Hospital Rule. But at this point, I cannot proceed since $f^{(n)}$ may not be continuous.

This is a problem from it *Calculus on Manifolds* by Spivak. The author suggests to calculate
$$\lim_{x \to a}\frac{f(x) - \sum_0^{n-1} \frac{f^{(i)}(a)}{i!}(x-a)^i}{(x-a)^n}$$
but I cannot see why it helps.

Also, I would like to add that the book does not talk about Taylor's expansion, or anything related. So far, were presented only very basic results of differentiation.

Comment: Part (a)'s 'if' is not correct. For example the function $f(x)=\begin{cases}0,&x\neq0\\1,&x=0\end{cases}$ and $g(x)=0+0(x-0)$ are equivalent at $a=0$ at order $1$, but $f$ is not differentiable. If they are something like $f$ being continuous, then it works: From $0=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(a+h)-a_0-a_1h}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(a+h)-a_0}{h}-a_1$, and the continuity of $f$ at $a$ you get that $a_0=f(a)$ and then $a_1=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$ is the derivative.

Comment: If you can show that the "hint" is equal to 0, this is equivalent to f and g being equal at order n.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy thanks for the comment. I didn't realize.

Comment: @pbn990 I cannot see the reason. The function has $\frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}(x-a)^n$ too.

Comment: The 'only if' in (a) is true as written. It is enough to take $a_0=f(a)$ and $a_1=f'(a)$. From $a_1=f'(a)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}=\frac{f(a+h)-a_0}{h}$, you get that $0=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(a+h)-a_0-a_1h}{h}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(a+h)-a_0-a_1(a+h-a)}{h}$.

Comment: For (b) don't take so many derivatives. Stop at $(n-1)$ L'Hospitals. You end up having to check that if $f^{(n-1)}$ is differentiable, then $0=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f^{(n-1)}(a+h)-f^{(n-1)}(a)-f^{(n)}(a)h}{h}$. This is just part (a) applied to $f^{(n-1)}$.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy I got your hints. I have a question only about one point. How the continuity of $f$ ensure that $a_0 = f(a)$?

Comment: You are asking in the 'if' direction of (a). It is knowing that $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(a+h)-a_0}{h}$ exists what tells you that $f(a+h)-a_0\to0$. Then continuity also tells you that $f(a+h)-f(a)\to0$. And finally these two tell you that $f(a)=a_0$.

Comment: @MoonLightSyzygy I see. I think you could make your comments an answer to the question. Thanks!